# Returning nullopt from a operator+ method

Tags: c++

I want to return a std::nullopt from a operator+ method if two vectors are not equal. If they are all good I want to return a *wynik* which is also a Vector element and it works fine. But the compiler keeps saying to me that *std* doesn't have the nullopt element. I have included optional, so it's not the case.

```cpp
#include <optional>
#include <iostream>

class Vector
{
public:
    int* vectr;
    Vector(int size)
    {
        vectr = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            vectr[i] = i;
        }
        std::cout << "Constructor was executed\n";
    }

    int sizevector(Vector& vector)
    {
        int size = sizeof(vector.vectr) / sizeof(vector.vectr[0]);
        return size;
    }

    Vector operator+(Vector& second)
    {
        int size = sizeof(this->vectr);
        if (sizeof(second)==size)
        {
            Vector result(size);
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                wynik.vectr[i] = this->vectr[i] + second.vectr[i];
            }
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            return std::nullopt;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The posted code does not `include` anything.

Comment: Did you `#include <optional>`?

Comment: `sizeof(drugi)` isn't going to be the number of elements that `drugi` contains. I think you want to write an actual `size()` method because otherwise you'll lose data from array-to-pointer decay.

Comment: *[wynik](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wynik#Noun)*  - *"1. result (that which results). 2. score (of a test or game) 3. effect"*

Comment: *[drugi](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/drugi#Adjective_2)* - *"other"*. Or *"second"* (numeral)

Comment: @PeterMortensen Thank You so much I can see that You made an effort going through my questions and anserws. I didn't even know that there were mistakes in them as noone have pointed them before. I changed the variable names as it was my first question here I didn't use pure English in my code yet.

Answer (score 4):

Your method needs to return `std::optional<Vector>`, so that `std::nullopt` can be a valid value of the return type.

However, I don't recommend doing this. It is highly unusual for the sum of two objects of type `T` to have type other than `T`, and will confuse people. It is better to throw an exception. If you are not allowed to throw an exception, then terminate the program. If you are not allowed to terminate the program, then return an empty vector.

Comment: It's university task so I don't have choice. The problem is that even when I use the std::optional<Vector> it still shows error ,,'Vector' : illegal use of this type as an expression" and ,,std don't have optional element" ( yes I include optional )

Comment: @PiotrNowakowski What C++ Standard do you have the compiler building to? `std::optional` is relatively recent and many compilers default to older Standards.

Comment: @user4581301 I use C++17

Comment: Groovy. Scratches that off the list.